# Why is a Hash Table with linked lists considered to have constant time complexity?

Tags: java, hash, time-complexity, hashtable

In my COMP class last night we learned about hashing and how it generally works when trying to find an element *x* in a hash table.

Our scenario was that we have a dataset of 1000 elements inside our table and we want to know if *x* is contained within that table.

Our professor drew up a Java array of 100 and said that to store these 1000 elements that each position of the array would contain a pointer to a Linked List where we would keep our elements.

Assuming the hashing function perfectly mapped each of the 1000 elements to a value between 0 and 99 and stored the element at the position in the array, there would be 1000/100 = 10 elements contained within each linked list.

Now to know whether *x* is in the table, we simply hash *x*, find it's hash value, lookup into the array at that slot and iterate over our linked list to check whether *x* is in the table.

My professor concluded by saying that the expected complexity of finding whether *x* is in the table is O(10) which is really just O(1). I cannot understand how this is the case. In my mind, if the dataset is N and the array size is n then it takes on average N/n steps to find *x* in the table. Isn't this by definition not constant time, because if we scale up the data set the time will still increase?

I've looked through Stack Overflow and online and everyone says hashing is expected time complexity of O(1) with some caveats. I have read people discuss chaining to reduce these caveats. Maybe I am missing something fundamental about determining time complexity.

TLDR: Why does it take O(1) time to lookup a value in a hash table when it seems to still be determined by how large your dataset is (therefore a function of N, therefore not constant).

Comment: http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/02/how-hashmap-works-in-java.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In my mind, if the dataset is N and the array size is n then it takes on average N/n steps to find x in the table.

This is a misconception, as hashing simply requires you to calculate the correct bucket (in this case, array index) that the object should be stored in.  This calculation will not become any more complex if the size of the data set changes.

These caveats that you speak of are most likely hash collisions: where multiple objects share the same hashCode; these can be prevented with a better hash function.

Comment: I think the OP's confusion is not about the complexity of evaluating the hash function, or how well it distributes the data. But rather that if we always use, say, 100 buckets, then as the data set gets larger we will inevitably have more and more items stored in each bucket, and the time required to find the item *inside* the bucket will increase. The key here, of course, is that we can choose a larger number of buckets to accommodate a larger data set without having the lists in each bucket get too long.

Comment: @CAW Theoretically yes, however I believe OP limits his `LinkedList`s to a capacity of 10.  In that case, the time that it takes to find an object in an already-full `Hashtable` will remain constant even if the size of the data set continues to increase.  But I agree that increasing the number of buckets is a valid solution as well.

Comment: I think OP was considering only limiting the number of buckets (i.e. the size of the array), rather than the size of the lists: "if the array size is n then it takes on average N/n steps to find x in the table" (meaning that each list contains on average N/n items, or 1000/100=10 in their example)

Comment: @CAW It would help is OP could provide us some clarification then if he's still confused.

Comment: @CAW Yes, that makes sense of course if you have a larger array then you're fine, you avoid collisions. However, in the example I provided there are collisions, so I don't understand how this can still be constant time.

Comment: @JacobG. The size of the LinkedList is not limited, they would start empty and as new collisions are stored they are simply appended to the linked list. If my dataset were now 1,000,000 and hashed and stored in 100 buckets then I would have 10,000 items per bucket, which would take on average 10,000  steps to find if x was contained in the table. This seems to scale with N.

Comment: @JonathanMongeau The problem with this question is that your professor provided you with an example of a `Hashtable` that generally isn't used in practice.  These `LinkedList`s are only appended to with different objects if they share the same hashCode; these collisions can be fixed with the use of a better hash function.  It is still O(1) to search for the correct bucket, but iterating through the list is, at worst, O(n).

Comment: @Jacob G. Assuming this example and even distribution. In this case if N < n then it's O(1) and if N>n it's at worse O(n)?

Comment: @JonathanMongeau If N <= n, then I believe `LinkedList`s wouldn't be required because every object in the data set can be mapped to its own array index.  However, if N > n, then `LinkedList`s would be required, and it would be, at worst, O(L) where L is the length of the `LinkedList` at the object's bucket (array index).  I hope this helps clear it up for you!

Comment: @Jacob G. It sort of does. Assuming no collisions O(1) and if there are then it's not. In my example though it's not right?

Comment: @JonathanMongeau In your example, you can think of a collision as adding an object to the `Hashtable` where the `LinkedList` at the bucket (array index) already has a size greater than or equal to 1.  Regardless if a collision occurs, you simply append onto the `LinkedList` which is O(1).  It wouldn't make sense to say that a collision can occur when searching for an object, only when adding them to the `Hashtable` itself.  In your example, the time complexity of adding will always be O(1), and the time complexity of searching can be said to be O(1) when N <= n, and O(L) otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

The complexity of a hashed collection for lookups is O(1) because the size of lists (or in Java's case, red-black trees) for each bucket is not dependent on N. Worst-case performance for `HashMap` if you have a very bad hash function is O(log N), but as the Javadocs point out, you get O(1) performance "assuming the hash function disperses the elements properly among the buckets". With proper dispersion the size of each bucket's collection is more-or-less fixed, and also small enough that constant factors generally overwhelm the polynomial factors.

Answer (score 1):

There is multiple issues here so I will address them 1 by 1:

Worst case analysis vs amortized analysis:

Worst case analysis refers to the absolute worst case scenario that your algorithm can be given relative to running time. As an example, if I am giving an array of unordered elements, and I am told to find an element in it, my best case scenario is when the element is at index [0] the worst possible thing that I can be given is when the element is at the end of the array, in which case if my data set is n, I run n times before finding the element. On the average case however the element is anywhere in the array so I will run n-k steps (where k is the number of elements after the element I am looking for in the array).

Worst case analysis of Hashtables:
There exists only 1 kind of Hashtable that has guaranteed constant time access O(1) to it's elements, Arrays. (And even then it's not actually true do to paging and the way OS's handle memory). The worst possible case that I could give you for a hash table is a data set where every element hashes to the same index. So for example if every single element hashes to index 1, due to collisions, the worst case running time for accessing a value is O(n). This is unavoidable, hashtables always have this behaviour.

Average and best case scenario of hashtables: 
You will rarely be given a set that gives you the worst possible case scenario. In general you can expect objects to be hashed to different indexes in your hashtable. Ideally the hash function hashes things in a very spread out manner so that objects get hashed to different indexes in the hash table.

In the specific example your teacher gave you, if 2 things get hashed to the same index, they get put in a linked list. So this is more or less how the table got constructed:

```
get element E
use the hashing function hash(E) to find the index i in the hash table
add e to the linjed list in hashTable[i].

repeat for all the elements in the data set
```

So now, let's say I want to find whether element E is on the table. Then:

```
do hash(E) to find the index i where E is potentially hashed

go to hashTable[i] and iterate through the linked list (up to 10 iterations)

If E is found, then E is in the Hash table, if E is not found, then E is not in the table
```

The reason why we can guarantee that E is not in the table if we can't find it, is because if it was, it would have been hashed to hashTable[i] so it HAS to be there, if it's on the table.

Comment: Actually for Java's `HashMap` the theoretical worst case for retrieval is O(log N).